# Multiple assignment using a Map's value instead of a variable with Groovy

Tags: syntax, groovy

In **Groovy**, I have a function that returns a triple.
I'd like to:

- **put** the first value returned in a `Map` for an arbitrary key and
- **assign** the two other values to variables.

I can do:

```
Map m = [:]
(day, month, year) = "12 February 2014".split(" ");
m["day"] = day;
```

But I would like to get rid of the variable `day`, like this:

```
Map m = [:]
(m["day"], month, year) = "12 February 2014".split(" ");
```

---

For some reason it seems to be not possible. This is what the compiler alerts me about:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/web/com/139223923319646/main.groovy: 2: expecting ')', found ',' @ line 2, column 10.
   (m["day"], month, year) = "12 February 2014".split(" ");
            ^
```

Would you guys be able to either help me or explain to me why this syntax cannot be used?

Comment: See the bottom of this page http://groovy.codehaus.org/Multiple+Assignment - they don't exactly say why, other than only use with 'simple variables, which means you map is not a 'simple' object.   Someone more Groovy-savvy, (like maybe Tim Yates!) might be able to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def dstr = "12 February 2014"
def m = [['day', 'month', 'year'], dstr.split( " " )].transpose()
                                                     .collectEntries()
```

To get

```
assert m == [ day:'12', month:'February', year:'2014' ]
```

But I'm not sure that's what you want...

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unfortunately, according to the [multiple assignment Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Multiple+Assignment).

> Currently only simple variables may be the target of multiple
>   assignment expressions, e.g. if you have a person class with firstname
>   and lastname fields, you can't currently do this:
>
> ```
> (p.firstname, p.lastname) = "My name".split()
> ```

Your first example is the best way to do this currently.

Comment: Oops, it seems that I just couldn't find that information myself! Sorry about that, and thank you for your reply ;)