# Grails split or tokenize

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to split each `_`: `1_XUIXETHU2_asd_18-2-2014_1392734922254.m4a`

and put them into

```
def test = new Test(id:1, code: XUIXETHU2, name:asd, date:18-2-2014, stamp: 1392734922254);
```

edited: Should I use `split` or `tokenizer`? Which is better? Why?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problem did you get?

Comment: I didn't want to give an answer before you showed us what you have tried. As a starting point, I remember @tim_yates [answered a question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21740457/2051952) few days ago which you need to see and try to implement in your case.

Comment: @tim_yates I haven't tried anything, my question is when to use split and when to use tokenizer from my use case. Or could give me an example of use case.

Comment: @dmahapatro I didn't asked for how to do, I asked if it's better for this type of string to add new Object using split or tokernizer. Or a example of use case using tokenizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use split. Here is sample code:

```
String tmp = "1_XUIXETHU2_asd_18-2-2014_1392734922254.m4a"
def splitted = tmp.split("_")


println splitted[0]
println splitted[1]
println splitted[2]
println splitted[3]
println splitted[4]
```

You can quickly test it with GroovyConsole.

Comment: Why not tokenizer, that gives me a list? Any difference, performance or it's simplier in this case?

Comment: No, it returns a array of strings : http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#split%28%29

Comment: Also it is a "Groovy" way to do it - simple and clean. Here is a difference between Split vs. Tokenizer: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2013/03/14/groovy-tokenize-vs-split/

Comment: Tokenizer returns the list